# How to forward root request to another directory with htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a root directory which has only test `index.php` file and `.htaccess`. Can you please help with forwarding root request (`example.com`) to child directory (`example.com/wp/index.php`). I don't need any redirects, because they will change the URL in the address bar.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule $^ /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is my `.htaccess` file in root directory for now. And with that `.htaccess`, server just return me `/index.php` (root index, not from sub directory).

So I don't think that it is very hard question, but I can't find where I'm making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule $^ /wp/index.php [L]
> ```

You have the regex anchors (end of string `$` and start of string `^`) round the wrong way. However, you could also have issues if you have a `DirectoryIndex` set (mod_dir will trigger an internal subrequest for `/index.php`, so the URL-path is not necessarily empty).

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /wp/index.php [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(index\.php)?$` matches either an empty URL-path, or `index.php` (the result of the mod_dir subrequest).

No need for the `<IfModule>` container and `RewriteBase` is not being used here.